# How to fill object by interface type?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have interface type:

```
interface IDate { 
    prev: {
        day: number;
        month: number;
        year: number;
    },
    next: {
        day: number;
        month: number;
        year: number;
    }
}
```

I tried to fill object using this interface:

```
 let obj<IDate> = {
        prev: {
            day: result.getDate(),
            month: result.getMonth() + 1,
            year: result.getFullYear
        },
        next: {
            day: result.getDate(),
            month: result.getMonth() + 1,
            year: result.getFullYear
        }
    }
```

It does not work for me, it has syntax error. I think problem in `keys` `next: {}`

```
It should be like:

interface IDate { 
    prev: {
        day: number;
        month: number;
        year: number;
    },
    next: {
        day: number;
        month: number;
        year: number;
    }
}
function addDays(date: Date, days: number) {
    var prevDate = new Date(date);
    let currentDate = new Date(date);

    currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + days);

    let obj: IDate =  {
        prev: {
            day: prevDate.getDate(),
            month: prevDate.getMonth() + 1,
            year: prevDate.getFullYear()
        },
        next: {
            day: currentDate.getDate(),
            month: currentDate.getMonth() + 1,
            year: currentDate.getFullYear()
        }
    }

    return obj;
}


var today = new Date();

let dt = addDays(today, 16);
```

Comment: What does the error say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Firstly `let obj: IDate = ...` to declare an object.
2. Secondly isnt `getFullYear` a function? If so then invoke it `getFullYear()`
3. Thirdly `getDate()` returns `Date` or `number`? If it's date then change field type to `Date`